# How many decimal places can the X and Y values of MySQL's point class have?

Tags: coordinates, point, mysql-8.0

I defined a column in my schema named `location POINT NOT NULL`. The point class specifies X- and Y-coordinate values. How many decimal places can these X and Y values have? I cannot find an exact definition – especially for the fractional part – for these properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL stores the spacial datatypes in the [WKB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-data-formats.html#gis-wkb-format) format.

This format uses double precision to store the X and Y co-ordinates. This means that it can store a precision of 16 decimal digits (53 bits of precision)

More information on double precision float format [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)